# How do I connect user's crypto wallet to discord server?

Tags: discord, cryptography

I have a discord server I want to be able to have users connect their crypto wallets too. Based off their holdings will allow special roles to be given

I'm not too sure how to set this up. ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED. Thank you.